# CloudKit private database reading and writing works without the user being logged into iCloud

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

I have been playing around with CloudKit and I was under the impression that the user needed to be logged-in into `iCloud` in order to use the private database in `CloudKit`, but I don't think it's true.

I'm testing an app that successfully communicates with the private database in `CloudKit`, I can read and write records to it. To my surprise I logged-off from my `iCloud` account and from the `Sandbox Account` and I can still read and write records from `CloudKit` which was unexpected, I was thinking that after logging off I wouldn't be able to communicate with `CloudKit`, in fact, I deleted the app from my phone, recompiled in Xcode and the app can still communicate with `CloudKit`.

Is this normal behavior, does `CloudKit` works without the user being logged into `iCloud`?

Can someone explain how does the connection to `CloudKit` works?

**Connection to the Private Database**
`let privateDatabase = CKContainer.default().database(with: .private)`

**Reading records**
`privateDatabase.perform(query, inZoneWith:nil){( results , error) in ... }`

**Writing Records**
`privateDatabase.save(ckRecord){ (record, error) in ...}`

Comment: The way you work with CloudKit is wrong.  Before you read or write to the database, you should check whether or not the user is logged in.

Comment: Well, that’s what I’m trying to do that’s why I logged off, to start implementing the check but I noticed that it works without being logged in, so I was wondering if I didn’t need to check since it works either way.

Comment: I don't see a problem if you are able to access the database when in fact you are not even signed in.  What does your web browser do when you try to access the dashboard?

Comment: I'm not understanding your point about the dashboard, that of course can be accessed with the right credentials, but that's the web; a totally different way of accessing the data. My only misunderstanding here is why is the `.private` database accessible if I'm not logged in. What I ultimately needed to know was whether I needed to check if the user was logged in or not to avoid redundant code/checks but based on your first comment it looks like it needs to be done, right? I'm assuming in production the behavior will be different and I will not be able to access data unless I'm logged in.

Comment: "I'm assuming in production the behavior will be different"  I doubt it.  And if that's what you think, you can possibly get your app rejected.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be able to write to CloudKit (public or private DB if not logged in)...

In my app, if I try to write to CloudKit (Public DB) without being logged into iCloud, I get an error:

> Error saving: Error saving record <CKRecordID: 0x7f91727cf0c0;
> recordName=xxx,
> zoneID=_defaultZone:**defaultOwner**> to server: WRITE operation not
> permitted

Are you certain the device is logged out?  And just to double check - why do you believe you are able to read/write?  Is it a lack of error or are you validating a save via the dashboard?

As someone recommended, check to see if they are logged in, using something like:

```
CKContainer.default().accountStatus { (accountStatus, error) in
  if accountStatus == .available {
      print("iCloud app container and private database is available")   
} else {
      print("iCloud not available \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")   
    }    
}
```